# Whenever i talk my computer attenuates others

Tags: macos, audio, video-streaming, audio-streaming

In every software i've tried in 1 to 1 video-calls my computer lowers the sound of others when i'm talking or my mic receives any sound.

It doesn't happen on group calls for what i've experienced.

Is there a way to stop this? I'm using a macOS Mojave.

Comment: Does this also happen when you use headphones? And what software did you try?

Comment: Yes, it does happen with headphones. I've tried FaceTime, Discord, Zoom.us, Meet and Hangouts.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be a problem on the receiving end? Does the person you're calling with use headphones?

Comment: I'm positive it's in my end. i've tried on my gf's macbook too and it does the same. Whenever one talks, they can't hear the other while talking.